# Is it possible that a closed infinite dimensional subspace of $\ell^2$ is closed in $\ell^1$ too.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $V$ a closed infinite dimensional subspace of $\ell^2$

Is it possibile that $V$ is closed in $\ell^1$ too ?

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Generally speaking, $\ell^2$ isn't even a subspace of $\ell^1$, so there's no way this is true in general.

Comment: Indeed the question does not seem to make sence..instead of subspace,don't mean subset?

Comment: A subspace inherits the topology of the space itself..but the subspce $(V,d_{l_2})$ is not a subspace of $(l_1,d_1)$ unless the two metrics define the same topology...which i do not believe it is the case

Comment: My question is if exist a closed infinite dimensional subspace of $\ell^2$ such that it is a closed subspace (not subset) of $\ell^1$

Comment: I do not belive that exists...

Comment: i'm not sure that not exists, for finite dimensional it's trivial that exists

Comment: You should have focused the question on whether an infinite dimensional subspace of $\ell^1$ can be closed in the $\ell^2$ norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that closed in $\ell^2$ implies closed in $\ell^1$ for any subspace of $\ell^1$.

Assume that $M \le \ell^1 \subset \ell^2$ is a closed subspace of $\ell_2$.

We shall prove that $M$ is closed in $\ell^1$ as well.

Take a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $M$ such that it is convergent in $\ell^1$ and set $x_n \xrightarrow{\|\cdot\|_1} x \in \ell^1$.

Since we have $\|\cdot\|_2 \le \|\cdot\|_1$, we get that $x_n \xrightarrow{\|\cdot\|_2} x$ also holds:

$$\|x_n - x\|_2 \le \|x_n - x\|_1 \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$

Since $M$ is closed in $\ell^2$, we have $x \in M$.

Thus, $M$ is closed in $\ell^1$.

In fact, the situation seems to be the same for any $p < q \in [1, +\infty\rangle$ since:

$$1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|x_n|^q}{\|x\|_q^q} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\underbrace{\frac{|x_n|}{\|x\|_q}}_{\le 1}\right)^q \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{|x_n|}{\|x\|_q}\right)^p = \frac{\|x\|_p^p}{\|x\|_q^p} \implies \|x\|_q \le \|x\|_p$$

Comment: Okay, but this leaves open a question of whether such a subspace exists to begin with (an infinite-dimensional subspace of $\ell^1$ that is closed in the $\ell^2$ norm).

Comment: @Michelle Yes, I haven't been able to come up with such a subspace.

Comment: @mechanodroid thanks for your answer

Comment: @Michelle thanks for your useful comments

Comment: @MateyMath You could consider posting a new question about the existence of such a subspace. It seems interesting.

Comment: I don't think there could be one. If there were, the formal identity would be an isomorphism from a closed  subspace of $\ell_1$ to a closed subspace of $\ell_2$. But every infinite dimensional closed subspace of $\ell_1$ contains a copy of $\ell_1$ while no subspace of $\ell_2$ does.

Comment: @DavidMitra I'm not familiar with that property, how would you prove it?

Comment: You can construct  a sequence in the subspace that is a small perturbation of a block basis of  the standard unit vector basis of $\ell_1$ (it will b equivalent to the standard basis of $\ell_1$). The details are in Diestel's *Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces* (and other texts, I imagine). There may be a simpler way of seeing why we can't have  such a subspace, but nothing comes to my mind at the moment.