# Could strict infinite dimensional closed subspaces of $\ell^1$ and $\ell^2$ be isomorphic?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Is it possible to find a strict infinite dimensional closed subspace of $\ell^1$ and a strict infinite dimensional closed subspace of $\ell^2$ such that they are isomorphic ?

Comment: Isomorphic as vector spaces ? Sure the subspace of finite length sequences. Now you probably meant **closed** subspaces (each closed for a different topology)

Comment: @reuns yes, i meant closed subspaces, thanks, now i edited the question

Comment: yes if there's a homeomorphism

Comment: So you want a subspace $A \subset l^1$ and a linear map $f:  A \to l^2$ such that $b \|x\|_1 \le \|f(x)\|_2 \le c \|x\|_1$

Comment: $A \subset \ell^1$ strict subspace infinite dimensional and $B \subset \ell^2$ and linear map $f: A \to B$ homeomorphism as you write

Comment: I don't think so, look at the comments under my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2436157/144766) on one of your previous questions. I don't understand the proof of the argument though.

Comment: thanks @mechanodroid i already read them i don't understand totally that proof too so i did this question, i think that any infinite dimensional subspace of $\ell^1$ is isomorphic to $\ell^1$ but $\ell^2$ is not isomorphic to $\ell^1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to embed $l^2$ into $l^1$.

Let $T\colon l^2 \to l^1$ a linear continuous . Since $e_n$ converges weakly to $0$ in $l^2$, $T(e_n)$ must converge weakly to $0$ in $l^1$. However, in $l^1$, if a sequence converges weakly to $0$, it also converges strongly to $0$ ( this is a result of Schur I guess, see [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42609/strong-and-weak-convergence-in-ell1) on this site). Therefore, $T(e_n)$ converges to $0$ in $l^1$. Since $e_n$ does not converge to $0$ in $l^2$, we conclude that $T$ is not an embedding.

Comment: Notice that every infinitely dimensional closed subspace of $l^2$ is isomorphic to $l^2$.

Comment: Every infinite-dimensional *closed* subspace of $\ell^2$ is isomorphic to $\ell^2$.

Comment: @mechanodroid: corrected that, thanks!

Comment: thanks @orangeskid for you answer

Comment: @Matey Math: no worries